# What's the difference between a normal/bare git repository?

Tags: git

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/git-convert-normal-to-bare-repository) says

> in a bar Git repository, there is no working copy and the folder
>   (let's call it repo.git) contains the actual repository data

however after experiment,I found it's not true.

There's still `.git` directory in a bare repository.

So what's the difference at all?

Answer (score 3):

Reiterating...

A standard git repository is a working copy with the git data stored in the `.git` directory.

A bare git repository does not have a working copy, and is in essence only the `.git` directory (but is not named `.git`, it's named whatever you called it).

That post you found is exactly correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this.  No directory named `.git` is present in a bare repository.

```
~/test$ git --bare init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/test/
~/test$ ls -a
.  ..  HEAD  branches  config  description  hooks  info  objects  refs
```

If you have one, then your bare repository isn't actually a bare repository.  What steps are you taking to create or clone your repository?

Comment: This isn't quite correct. See my answer.

Comment: @bahamat I am aware that a bare repo is equivalent to the contents of the `.git` directory of a normal repo.  I meant, in the quite literal sense, that a bare repo doesn't contain a directory named `.git`.  He's got one, which is why I asked how he's creating his clone.

Comment: @bahamat After a re-read, I can see why you felt the need to clarify.  I've edited to make the aspects of the answer less opaque.  Thanks, and +1 to your answer.